# How to range over nested struct in golang?

Tags: dictionary, go

I am new to Golang:
These are my defined struct:

```
type Name map[string]Info

type Info struct {
    Addresses string                             `json:"addresses"`
    Host   map[string]Server                     `json:"host"`
}

type Server struct {
   Ipaddress     string        `json:"ip"`
   Status        string        `json:"status"`
}

var result Name
```

after unmarshalling Json i get:

```
result = [
    user1:{
        192.168.98.0/26
        map[
            xx.user1.domain.com:{192.168.98.1 good} 
            xx.user1.domain.com:{192.168.98.3 good} 
            xx.user1.domain.com:{192.168.98.4 Bad}
        ]
    } 
    user2: {
        192.168.99.0/26
        map[
            xx.user2.domain.com:{192.168.99.1 good}
        ]
    }
]
```

How to range over this Json to get the ipaddress which has a status=="good" for the particular user ?

I am trying to do this way:

```
  for j , _ := range result["user1"].Servers {
     if a := result["user1"].Servers[j]); a == "good" {
      //Problem is here I am not sure how to further scan the ip and status
      //do something
```

}

```
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What's not working? If you can show us the code you're using to try and walk the structure that'll help us guide you.

Comment: There're either `range` or `for`. You don't have other options.

Comment: `fmt.Printf()` expects a string and formatting, you passed in your defined struct `Server` instead of the type `string`...  Try `fmt.Println()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
for _ , i := range result {
    for  _, j := range i.Host {
        if j.Status == "good" {
            server := j.Ip
        }
    }
}
```